# Objects are not valid as a React child when child props change dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to abstract a modal that I use often inside my app, I'm able to use it inside another screen that should send a prop that comes from a TextInput component inside this other screen. The problem is, when I leave the TextInput component empty it renders the Modal normally but when I type anything to it, it crashes raising an `Objects are not valid as a react child` error. I tried using `React.Children` to map the children array a couple of ways but it still crashed.

The Main component (FirstStep being the Other Screen):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FirstStep from "./components/firstStep";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default function signInScreen({ navigation, ...props }) {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return (
                <FirstStep
                    username={username}
                    setUsername={setUsername}
                    setStep={setStep}
                    navigate={navigation.navigate}
                />
            )
        default:
            return <Text>Ola</Text>
    }
}
```

[The Other Screen that calls the modal with children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM7rF.png)

```
export default function firstStep({ username, setUsername, setStep, navigate }) {
    const [modalVisibility, setModalVisibility] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Container>
            <InformationModal
                visibility={modalVisibility}
                transparency={true}
            >
                <ModalHeader>
                    <ModalHeaderText color={light_gray}>Ola, <ModalHeaderText color={light_green}>{username}</ModalHeaderText></ModalHeaderText>
                </ModalHeader>
            </InformationModal>
            <NameInput
                placeholder="Nome"
                placeholderTextColor={light_green}
                onSubmitEditing={() => setStep(1)}
                value={username}
                onChange={value => setUsername(value)}
            />
    ...
```

[Modal (I actually tried both functional and class components)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kh9y.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Container, SubContainer } from './styles';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default class InformationModal extends Component {
    render() {
        const children = this.props.children;
        const { height, visibility, transparency, animationType } = this.props;

        return (
            <Modal
                visible={visibility}
                transparent={transparency}
                animationType={animationType}
            >
                <Container>
                    <SubContainer height={height}>
                        <View>
                            {children}
                        </View>
                    </SubContainer>
                </Container>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

[The error raised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo7Fz.jpg)

[Update 1: The TextInput Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFPj.png) using useState hooks

Comment: can you provide what your input handler is doing exactly on the TextInput Component?

Comment: Added a picture of the component

Comment: I mean the actual event handler function so in your case setUsername( value )

Comment: `const [username, setUsername] = useState("");` comes from useState which is defined inside a main component, so the whole thing is:
Main (which defines setUsername and passed as props) ---> Other Screen ---> Modal

Comment: Can you include code as text rather than as images? It makes it easier for others to copy and paste your code to test ideas.

Comment: Done, ty for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Actually was able to fix this. My mistake, instead of using `onChangeText` I was using React's `onChage` on my input component which sends an object to the modal instead of just text.